# AxiosStatic has no index signature

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm converting a hook I recently made use of to Typescript and getting the below error

```
(alias) const axios: AxiosStatic
import axios
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'AxiosStatic' has no index signature. Did you mean to call 'axios.get'?ts(7052)
```

Which is spawning from the below code.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    axios[method](url, data, config)
        .then((res) => {
            setResponse(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            setError(err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            setloading(false);
        });
};
```

I believe specifically it's related to axios[method]

I was using this previously so I could pass in various request types dynamically. I'm unsure of how to resolve the above error using best typescript practices.

These values are retrieved from the following in the following

```
({ url, method, data })
```

P.S: I'm aware that there might be other issues in the snippet but I'll resovle those as they're just related to types.

Comment: Restrict `method`'s type from any string to only keys of `axios`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is complaining because `method` could potentially be any string and not a key of `axios`. You can fix this by making its type a key of `axios`.

First a union of all methods axios supports:

```
type Methods = "head" | "options" | "put" | "post" | "patch" | "delete" | "get";
```

Then if this is a function we can make the parameter type `Methods`:

```
function foo(method: Methods) {
    axios[method] // works
    // ...
}
```

Or if it's a variable:

```
let method: Method = ...;
```

You may need to use a cast too:

```
let method = ... as Method;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQwB7AgZzgMyhEcBEyqa+A3AFDkwCeYApnALJ0wAWEAJhgLwGt0IO+OAB8CEMDFQA7EqIJgArjGFj8kNCvnqEMAMatVBDnQA2LOkfwBzFmUom9phFAZ6Is+CBbsOALiYfTjQKciJ0AG1vNk4AXVI4AHpEuGkIAHc4YHg9BGk4ACMGRTQ6Djg-ABEgA)